# Why don't 2 commands work in the aiogram telegram bot

Tags: python, aiogram

Good afternoon, I'm new to python development! there is a telegram bot code in which there are 2 commands, only the one that is higher in the code is processed, how to fix it

The bot code is below, please help me figure it out

```
import os
import asyncio
import sqlite3
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware

from token_data import TELEGRAM_TOKEN


# Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных SQLite
conn = sqlite3.connect('user.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn2 = sqlite3.connect('ip_addresses.db')
cursor2 = conn2.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
cursor2.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
tables = cursor.fetchall()
tables2 = cursor2.fetchall()
print(tables, tables2)
# Создаем таблицу пользователей, если она не существует
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    username TEXT,
                    first_name TEXT,
                    last_name TEXT,
                    blok INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                    ip_address TEXT
                )''')
conn.commit()

# Здесь нужно указать токен вашего бота
bot = Bot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

# Путь к папке, которую бот будет просматривать
base_folder = 'instr'

# Переменная для хранения выбранного пути
current_path = base_folder

# Настройка логирования
log_file = 'bot.log'
max_log_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024  # 5 МБ
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s')
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename=log_file, mode='a', maxBytes=max_log_size, backupCount=1)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s'))
logging.getLogger().addHandler(file_handler)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['/29'])
async def process_29_command(message: types.Message):
    # Получаем SAP объекта из сообщения пользователя
    await message.reply(text="Введите SAP объекта:")
    # Ожидаем ввод пользователя

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT)
async def handle_sap_input(message: types.Message):
    sap = (message.text).upper()


    # Включение переданного значения sap в SQL-запрос
    cursor2.execute("SELECT subnet_ip FROM ip_addresses WHERE sap = ?", (sap,))
    try:
        rows = cursor2.fetchall()
        last_part = [row[0].split(".")[-1] for row in rows]
        first_part = [row[0].split(".")[:3] for row in rows]
        message_list = []

        for i, row in enumerate(rows):

            ip_parts = first_part[i]  # Первые три октета адреса

            dict_entry = {f'Сервер {i + 1}': '.'.join(ip_parts)}  # Создание словаря с именем сервера и адресом
            message_list.append(dict_entry)  # Добавление словаря в список message
        # для сети с последним октетом 0
        if int(last_part[0]) == 0:
            message_vlan12 = [
                'VLAN 12 - Для сервера магазина и удаленного управления',
                {'Плата удаленного управления резервного сервера': '.'.join(
                    first_part[0] + ['3'])},
                {'Плата удаленного управления сервером': '.'.join(
                    first_part[0] + ['4'])},
                {'Сервер BO резервный': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['5'])},
                {'Сервер BP': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['6'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['1'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.248'}
            ]
            message_vlan10 = [
                'VLAN 10 - для CashControl',
                {'Сервер CashControl': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['11'])},
                {'2й Сервер CashControl': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['12'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['9'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.248'}
            ]
            message_vlan6 = [
                'VLAN 6 - для касс и КСО',
                {'Кассы': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['98-112'])},
                {'КСО зоны кофе': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['113-114'])},
                {'КСО': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['115-126'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['97'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.224'}
            ]
            message_vlan4 = [
                'VLAN 4 - для устройств, которым не требуется взаимодействие с сервером BO',
                {'Сервер радио 5': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['34'])},
                {'Биометрический терминал': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['44'])},
                {'Сервер для видеоаналитики СБ': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['45'])},
                {'ЕСУМ (инфокиоск, LED-панель': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['46-52'])},
                {'Хлебопечи': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['54-55'])},
                {'Оборудование ПЭС(ЦХМ)': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['59'])},
                {'Оборудование ПЭС(АСКУЭ)АССД': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['60'])},
                {'Оборудование ПЭС(Умный щит)': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['61'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['33'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.224'}

            ]
            message_vlan8 = [
                'VLAN 8 - для устройств, которым требуется доступ по UDP к системам снаружи магазина и к серверу BO',
                {'МФУ': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['18'])},
                {'Принтер': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['19'])},
                {'Сервер электронных ценников ESL': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['25'])},
                {'Точки доступа электронных ценников': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['26-30'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['17'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.240'}
            ]
            message_vlan2 = [
                'VLAN 2 - для устройств, подключаемых по проводу и которым не требуется прямой доступ к внешним системам',
                {'Стационарный термопринтер': '192.168.3.25-26'},
                {'Весы для касс самообслуживания (SWS)(Даркстор)': '192.168.3.30-32'},
                {'Прайсчекер WINCE': '192.168.3.100-103'},
                {'Шлюз': '192.168.3.1'},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.0'}
            ]
            message_vlan33 = [
                'VLAN 33 - для устройств, подключаемых по Wi-Fi и которым не требуется прямой доступ к внешним системам',
                {'Мобильный принтер': '192.168.1.10-14'},
                {'Весы для касс самообслуживания (SWS)(Даркстор)': '192.168.1.16-18'},
                {'Шлюз': '192.168.1.1'},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.0'}
            ]
            await message.answer(message_vlan12)
            await message.answer(message_vlan10)
            await message.answer(message_vlan6)
            await message.answer(message_vlan4)
            await message.answer(message_vlan8)
            await message.answer(message_vlan2)
            await message.answer(message_vlan33)

        # для сети с последним октетом 128
        elif int(last_part[0]) == 128:
            message_vlan12 = [
                'VLAN 12 - Для сервера магазина и удаленного управления',
                {'Плата удаленного управления резервного сервера': '.'.join(
                    first_part[0] + ['131'])},
                {'Плата удаленного управления сервером': '.'.join(
                    first_part[0] + ['132'])},
                {'Сервер BO резервный': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['133'])},
                {'Сервер BP': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['134'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['129'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.248'}
            ]
            message_vlan10 = [
                'VLAN 10 - для CashControl',
                {'Сервер CashControl': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['139'])},
                {'2й Сервер CashControl': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['140'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['137'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.248'}
            ]
            message_vlan6 = [
                'VLAN 6 - для касс и КСО',
                {'Кассы': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['226-240'])},
                {'КСО зоны кофе': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['241-242'])},
                {'КСО': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['243-254'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['225'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.224'}
            ]
            message_vlan4 = [
                'VLAN 4 - для устройств, которым не требуется взаимодействие с сервером BO',
                {'Сервер радио 5': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['162'])},
                {'Биометрический терминал': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['172'])},
                {'Сервер для видеоаналитики СБ': '.'.join(
                    first_part[0] + ['173'])},
                {'ЕСУМ (инфокиоск, LED-панель': '.'.join(
                    first_part[0] + ['174-180'])},
                {'Хлебопечи': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['182-183'])},
                {'Оборудование ПЭС(ЦХМ)': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['187'])},
                {'Оборудование ПЭС(АСКУЭ)АССД': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['188'])},
                {'Оборудование ПЭС(Умный щит)': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['189'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['161'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.224'}

            ]
            message_vlan8 = [
                'VLAN 8 - для устройств, которым требуется доступ по UDP к системам снаружи магазина и к серверу BO',
                {'МФУ': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['146'])},
                {'Принтер': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['147'])},
                {'Сервер электронных ценников ESL': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['153'])},
                {'Точки доступа электронных ценников': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['154-158'])},
                {'Шлюз': '.'.join(first_part[0] + ['145'])},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.240'}
            ]
            message_vlan2 = [
                'VLAN 2 - для устройств, подключаемых по проводу и которым не требуется прямой доступ к внешним системам',
                {'Стационарный термопринтер': '192.168.3.25-26'},
                {'Весы для касс самообслуживания (SWS)(Даркстор)': '192.168.3.30-32'},
                {'Прайсчекер WINCE': '192.168.3.100-103'},
                {'Шлюз': '192.168.3.1'},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.0'}
            ]
            message_vlan33 = [
                'VLAN 33 - для устройств, подключаемых по Wi-Fi и которым не требуется прямой доступ к внешним системам',
                {'Мобильный принтер': '192.168.1.10-14'},
                {'Весы для касс самообслуживания (SWS)(Даркстор)': '192.168.1.16-18'},
                {'Шлюз': '192.168.1.1'},
                {'Маска': '255.255.255.0'}
            ]
            await message.answer(message_vlan12)
            await message.answer(message_vlan10)
            await message.answer(message_vlan6)
            await message.answer(message_vlan4)
            await message.answer(message_vlan8)
            await message.answer(message_vlan2)
            await message.answer(message_vlan33)
        else:
            await message.answer('Данный объект ещё не переведен')

    except: await message.answer('Введенное значение не является SAP')




@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def handle_start(message: types.Message):
    # Сохраняем информацию о пользователе в базе данных
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name
    last_name = message.from_user.last_name

    cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (id, username, first_name, last_name, blok) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 1)",
                   (user_id, username, first_name, last_name))
    conn.commit()

    # Получаем имя пользователя для приветствия
    if first_name is not None:
        name = first_name
    elif username is not None:
        name = username
    else:
        name = "User"

    # Проверяем, заблокирован ли пользователь
    cursor.execute("SELECT blok FROM users WHERE id = ?", (user_id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    if result is not None and result[0] == 1:
        # Пользователь заблокирован, отправляем сообщение с отказом в доступе
        await message.answer(f'''Вам запрещен доступ к боту. Необходимо обратиться к вашему старшему инженеру для
        получения доступа. Обязательно необходимо предоставить Ваш ID.''')
        await message.answer(f'Ваш ID {user_id}')
        return

    # Получаем файлы и папки в текущем каталоге
    files = []
    folders = []

    for item in os.listdir(current_path):
        item_path = os.path.join(current_path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(item_path):
            files.append(item)
        elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
            folders.append(item)

    # Создаем клавиатуру с папками и файлами в качестве кнопок
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)

    # Добавляем кнопку "Инфо" в самом верху, только если текущий путь - базовый каталог
    if current_path == base_folder:
        keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton('Инфо. Актуальные образы'))


    # Добавляем кнопку "Назад", если текущий путь не является базовым каталогом
    if current_path != base_folder:
        keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton('Назад'))

    for folder in folders:
        keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(folder))

    for file in files:
        keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(file))

    # Отправляем приветственное сообщение с клавиатурой
    await message.answer(f"Выберите папку или файл:", reply_markup=keyboard)



# Обработчик кнопки "Инфо"
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == 'Инфо. Актуальные образы')
async def handle_info(message: types.Message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id

        # Получаем данные из таблицы "images"
        # Получаем все строки из таблицы "images"
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM images")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        if rows:

            for row in rows:
                info_message = f"Актуальные образы {row[0]} :\n"
                info_message += f"\n"
                info_message += f"\n"
                info_message += f"BO: {row[1]}\n"
                info_message += f"\n"
                info_message += f"POS все кроме HP и NCR XR4: {row[2]}\n"
                info_message += f"\n"
                info_message += f"POS HP и NCR XR4: {row[3]}\n"
                info_message += f"\n"
                info_message += f"КСО: {row[4]}\n"
                info_message += f"\n"
                info_message += f"PC: {row[5]}\n"
                await message.answer(info_message)
        else:
            await message.answer("В таблице images нет данных для отображения.")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
        await message.answer("Произошла ошибка при выполнении операции. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.")


# Обработчик нажатия кнопок с папками и файлами
@dp.message_handler()
async def handle_folder_or_file(message: types.Message):
    global current_path

    try:
        # Проверяем, заблокирован ли пользователь
        cursor.execute("SELECT blok FROM users WHERE id = ?", (message.from_user.id,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is not None and result[0] == 1:
            # Пользователь заблокирован, отправляем сообщение с отказом в доступе
            await message.answer("Вам запрещен доступ к боту.")
            return

        chosen_item = message.text
        chosen_item_path = os.path.join(current_path, chosen_item)

        if chosen_item == 'Назад':
            # Если выбрана кнопка "Назад", обновляем текущий путь на родительскую папку
            parent_path = os.path.dirname(current_path)
            if parent_path.startswith(base_folder):
                current_path = parent_path
            else:
                await message.answer("Вы достигли верхней директории.")
                return
            await handle_start(message)
        elif chosen_item == 'Инфо. Актуальные образы':
            current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
            file_path = os.path.join(current_folder, 'help.txt')
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                    content = f.read()
                await message.answer(content)
            else:
                await message.answer("Файл 'help.txt' не найден.")
        elif os.path.isfile(chosen_item_path):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(chosen_item_path)
            # Проверяем, если размер файла больше 50 МБ (в байтах)
            if file_size > 50 * 1024 * 1024:
                await message.answer("Файлы размером более 50 МБ нельзя скачивать."
                                     "Для скачивания файлов большого объема,"
                                     "подключитесь к FTP в соответствующий раздел")
                logging.info(f"Запрос файла объемом более 50 МБ {current_path}, файл {chosen_item}"
                             f" запросил пользователь ID {message.from_user.id}")
            else:
                # Если выбран файл, и его размер допустим, отправляем его пользователю
                with open(chosen_item_path, 'rb') as f:
                    await message.answer_document(f)
        elif os.path.isdir(chosen_item_path):
            # Проверяем, если выбрана папка, но она выше базовой папки
            if not chosen_item_path.startswith(base_folder):
                await message.answer("Вы достигли верхней директории.")
                return

            # Если выбрана папка, обновляем текущий путь и отправляем список файлов и папок
            current_path = chosen_item_path
            await handle_start(message)

        # Сохраняем изменения в базе данных
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        # Записываем ошибку в лог и уведомляем пользователя о неполадке
        logging.error(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
        await message.answer("Произошла ошибка при выполнении операции. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.")







# Запускаем бота

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    dp.register_message_handler(handle_start, commands=['start'])
    dp.register_message_handler(process_29_command, commands=['29'])

    loop.create_task(dp.start_polling())
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Бот остановлен пользователем.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Бот остановлен из-за неожиданной ошибки: {e}")
    finally:
        # Закрываем соединение с базой данных при остановке бота
        conn.close()
        conn2.close()
```

I tried swapping and registering in main , I also tried to launch through the button on the keyboard , but without success

Comment: You haven't posted any error and you have posted a ton of code. Make a minimal reproducible version of your code and put the error you are getting

Comment: hello! there is no error, just the command is not processed

Comment: What command? What specific part of your code is not working properly? Have you debugged the code and see if that part returns any value?

Comment: in the current implementation, the /start command does not work, depending on who is above that command and works, but it is not possible for both commands to work so that the user can call this or that command.